# collection vs list vs arrays as return type for EJB method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, ejb

I was recently told that collection should be preferred to List as the return value of an EJB method. The argument is that in general collection is more generic i.e. gives you to change the underlying data structure without impacting the clients. And if this is the flexibility you want to have as a designer then using collection will make better sense. But then wouldn't it make more sense to return just an array instead of collection?

And what are performance impacts if any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- Prefer collections over arrays; Use generics
- Use interfaces instead of concrete classes

Then you usually have 4 options: `List`, `Set`,  `Collection` and `Iterable`. There it depends what is the semantics you want to include.

- If it is an internal API - decide it based on the characteristics of the collection:

  - does it only hold unique items? `Set`
  - will clients need random access to it? `List`
  - will clients need to modify it (add, remove) (without the above two characteristics)? `Collection`
  - will clients just need to iterate it? `Iterable`
- If it's a web service it doesn't matter - it is serialized the same way.

(Note: there are some collection interfaces with more specific semantics: `Queue`, `Deque`, `Map`, `Bag`, `Multiset`, etc. - but it will be fairly obvious when you need to return them)

Comment: +1 - Iterable is a great "collection" to return if you need to deal with potentially large datasets.

Comment: Also note that `Collection` has a `size()` method while `Iterable` doesn't, and it's not worth restricting the clients to iterate over an `Iterable` just to get the size. So my addition is: "will clients need to modify it `or will most probably need the size of it`".

Answer (score 5):

Collections in general are preferable over arrays, especially since Java5, where they were turned generic. This gives you type safety, and lots of potential extra features which aren't available in arrays (e.g. Set / Queue etc. behaviour) - these are in fact not directly comparable to arrays at all. Among collections, `ArrayList` is the direct analogy of an array, and - being implemented on top of an array - its performance is comparable to a native array.

As for Collection vs List (or some other more specific interface), I personally would prefer the more specific interface, as the characteristics and behaviour of e.g. a List vs a Set is very different. In a well designed interface, you should know (and specify) in advance whether you return e.g. a Set, Dequeue or List. If you return a Collection, all your clients can do (apart from adding/removing elements) is to iterate through it, which may not be enough for them.

Comment: i agree with the first paragraph.  i don't think the second makes sense as a general rule.  it really depends on what the collection means to the caller.  if you return a List, it can imply that the returned data has some sort of order.  if that's what you _want_ to imply great.  otherwise, i would prefer Collection.  if the data is unique, then you should probably use Set.  then again, if it is sorted, you may want SortedSet.  In other words, you should choose the interface based on the constraints you want to convey to the caller.

Comment: @jtahlborn, that's why I stated this is my personal opinion. But if all the caller needs is iterate over the elements, a Collection is just fine.

Comment: it's better with the clarification.  it wasn't clear before _why_ you preferred one way over the other, just that you thought it was "better".  i was trying to get at the underlying reason as to why it was better, i.e. it conveys information about the data to the Caller.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using a `Collection` opposed to a more specific interface like a `List` or a `Set` is meant to be done intentionally. You would be using the `Collection` interface for all instances where a more specific interface extends the `Collection` interface, i.e. for true collections. But, you cannot do the same for other interfaces like a `Map` which represent mappings rather than collections. This would imply that your EJB interface signtaures ought to be thought of very carefully.

As pointed out in the other answer by SJuan, if you intend to return an ordered collection, then you *must* be using a `List`. You can document this behavior of your interface, but that is missing the point; the method signature ought to convey this. Also, note that `List`s may contain duplicates, so if you intend to return a collection without duplicates, it makes a lot more sense to return a `Set` instead of a `List` or a `Collection`. To restate my opinion, the collection returned by an EJB method should reflect the properties of the collection accurately as far as possible, without referencing a concrete type; attempting to rely on documentation to convey this might not have the desired results during development of EJB clients.

On the topic of using Arrays, I would recommend avoiding them, especially arrays of type `Object[]`. It is easy to abuse these, and convert them into weakly typed data transfer objects, thereby necessitating extensive documentation on how every element of the array ought to be processed. The same advice applies to Collections, but most folks tend to abuse arrays instead of collections, or at least that has been my observation.

The last note leads to the use of generics in collections. If your container (and indirectly the version of the EJB specification) allows you to use generified interfaces for your methods, then do use them for the extra type safety. After all, getting your client to process `List<DomainObject>` is a better design decision than letting the client process a `List` or a `List<Object>`. I would emphasize on the aspect of container support once again, as EJB 2.x interfaces do not support generics (that has been my observation), while EJB 3.x supports generics (but container can choke at deployment or runtime), and would require your local and remote interfaces to be coded in a particular manner; [for instance WebLogic 10.3.x](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/implementing.html#wp1129878) requires you to specify the generics in a super interface that is extended as a local/remote interface.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not an issue only with EJB. This applies to all method definitions.

In fact, the same is also said of the definition of parameters and variables:

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The broader the definition that is made, the more freedom at the time of implementation. Say that I define:

```
 public class Numbers {
   public ArrayList getPrimesUnder(int N) {
   }
 }
```

Let's say that I find that I can use someone's else library method to do that, but it returns a Vector instead of an ArrayList. Now, I'll have to risk breaking code that calls to my method or I'll have to copy the data from the Vector to an ArrayList. If I had defined the return type as List, I could return any instance of it.

Why not use Collection in this case? Because List is an specialization of Collection that is ordered. If I want to return my results ordered, then I'll use List. If they are not ordered, then Collection suits better.