# Is it better to return a java.util.List or a java.util.Collection from my Restful Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Restful web service that I am writing. It is a simple dump of a database table using getResultList.  The EJB call looks like this  -

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Todo e");

List<Todo> ret = (List<Todo>) query.getResultList();
return ret;
```

The Restful web service could return this as a java.util.List since thats what it is coming out of getResultList.  However, would it be a better practice to return it as a java.util.Collection since that is more generic?

Comment: I would strongly say to do some testing and get the answer by yourself, but for this case I recommend using `List` instead.

Comment: Does the order matter?  If yes, use a `List`, if not, use a `Collection`.  (Or even an `Iterable`, if you don't need the `size`.)

Comment: I agree with Luiggi, but it also depends on your JSON/XML/other generator. The generator might not be setup for serializing a Collection as well as a List.

Comment: Ordinarily I would say returning a reference to a more abstract type would be better as it decouples you from the exact underlying type, leaving you the freedom to later change the underlying implementation.  However, I think `List` is probably abstract enough in this case.  Of course, if `Collection` exposes methods you require, then use that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and look at the consumer as well. Most people do Java to Java web services, so I guess this won't be a problem, but when interacting with other PLs like C# the headache begins... so I prefer to use a standard between languages and keep the `List`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, using a `List` will announce that the ordering matters. So, using `Collection` communicates your intention clearer (as you don't have an ordering).

That said, many programmers simply use `List` in this situation. Also, if you might add ordering in the future, using a `List` now may be better. Therefore, t.b.h I think either would be fine.

As for `Iterable`, I would not use it as it's less commonly used and confuse people, unless the underlying thing is a generator (lazily loads value on request).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers/comments

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the requirement. If you wanted to make the implementation more generic and also if you are not sure at where the may be used, `Collection` usage is more advisable. 
[Please find why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667903/collection-vs-list-vs-arrays-as-return-type-for-ejb-method)

Answer (score -1):

You should always use subtypes, unless there's a valid reason to use supertype. Why? because it is important to communicate exactly what your API clients should expect as a result. Clear ambiguities as much as possible by using the correct design.

Comment: If this advice was followed it would mean returning ArrayList or LinkedList, which is almost always a bad idea. 'Correct design' just begs the question. -1